# ASP.NET MVC 5 Simple Membership Initialization Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, simplemembership

I recently updated an MVC 4 site using simple membership to MVC 5.
I then have a line in a controller that uses the membership provider:

```
SimpleMembershipProvider provider = new SimpleMembershipProvider();
if (provider.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name) == id)
```

However on that controller I get the message:

> You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method
>   before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call
>   should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.

So I googled it and applied the stackoverflow suggestion in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839032/you-must-call-the-websecurity-initializedatabaseconnection-method-before-you-c) to global.asax.
That didnt work so I applied it to the AuthConfig in App_start folder. That also doesnt work.

Has anyone found how to get this working in MVC 5?
Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry what a bad oversight!
I should be using the WebSecurity class, not the simpleMembershipProvider class.
So i simply updated both the lines in the controller above to:

```
if (WebSecurity.CurrentUserId == id)
```

And the problem is gone.